# Jenkins not able to execute build.xml file. Should jenkins run by root user?

Tags: shell, svn, ant, jenkins, hudson

I have a shell script `Test.sh`.I have created an ant `build.xml` file to run this shell script.

In Jenkins, I am triggering this `build.xml`. `Test.sh` contains svn repository urls which checks out the source code.

When I build the this job in Jenkins, it shows an error like  *Password for 'jenkins': Authentication realm:* and "*authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge"*.

Why does this shows up? When I run the `build.xml` file from my machine svn checkout works fine without any authentication.

How should I configure Jenkins to execute in similar way when `build.xml` is triggered. Should we run jenkins be run as root ?

Answer (score 2):

First, what do you mean by *triggered*?

In Jenkins, you can trigger builds in many ways. You can remotely execute a build via a URL, You can have the build run at particular times, or you can have the build run when a change is detected in the repository. How are you triggering the build.

Also, how is Jenkins getting this `build.xml` and this `Test.sh`. You realize that Jenkins can run the `Test.sh` itself without having to build an Ant script to do this? Also, you can let Jenkins to the checkout for you. That's one of the big reasons to use Jenkins.

Should you run Jenkins as root? Absolutely not. Jenkins should run as its own user. Giving Jenkins root access could lead to unintended trouble. Imagine if a build script contained `rm -rf /`. Run Jenkins as its own user, and give that particular user *read only* access to your repository (unless you have Jenkins do commits or make tags).

Why are you getting these errors?  When does Jenkins get these errors? When you go into Jenkins itself? When You trigger the build? When Jenkins attempts to checkout code from your version control system? If it's the last one, it could be that Jenkins  doesn't have permission. When you setup the job, and you do a checkout, you need to make sure that there are checkout credentials set.

Can you give me a bit more explanation how this job is setup? Why do you have a file that is a shell script that is put into a build.xml that tells you what directories to checkout? Why not let Jenkins handle this itself? What are you trying to build? Is this a Java app? (you're using `build.xml`).

---

## Addendum

> How do i run shell script without using by build file can you give me an example ? What am trying to do is , we have an web application which requires trunk source , sql file , installation path and some more additional files in our SVN repositories. Now the shell script checksout all the necessary files without authorization and create an instance of our application in /var/www folder. Now what i have to do is using jenkins i have to invoke this build.xml file (which consists of shell script) every day at 7:PM so that after it has been done we can run automation scripts on that instance. –  /

I have a feeling you don't understands how Jenkins works…

Jenkins can run a wide variety of tasks and not just Ant. You can add a build step and specify what you want. One of the choices is to run a shell script.

Jenkins is a continuous build engine. It's not an installer and it's not a replacement for crontab.

Jenkins builds an application in its work area. You can build based upon a particular time, on demand, or whenever something changes in your project. Jenkins will build, run tests, make documentation, and store artifacts for deployment.

I use the [promoted build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) to actually deploy an artifact. You can use the FTP and SCP plugins to copy files into a deploy area as part of the build process too.

I would make a few recommendations:

- Use the `svn:externals` property to get all of your disparate parts of your build under a single Subversion project. A single checkout will get everything you need for your deployment. Just be careful in how you specify the various pieces. Use revision numbers or tags to *freeze* various parts of the repository, or use relative tags, so everything is on a single branch.
- If something needs root access, use `sudo`. You can setup `sudo` to not require a password for a particular user and limit the commands that can be run as root. By the way, is `/var/www` owned by root? It shouldn't be. It should be owned by the process that runs `httd` which shouldn't be root either.
- Some sites have their web page directory area a Subversion working directory. A `svn update` will install what they need.

By the way, you can setup a Jenkins task to do an install like you're doing, but there are probably better tools available.

Comment: My jenkins job doesn't have any svn configuration , but i have said it to invoke ant build. There i have given the path to the build.xml file which inturns runs the shell script as mentioned above. This shell script was given by my operations team which i have to invoke it for each build. Am getting these errors due to svn access. If we run this shell script in VM it never asks for svn access but in jenkins it fails to invoke the ant saying authorization failed in svn. Now my question is how to make jenkins work for my build file without any authorization?

Comment: How do i run shell script without using by build file can you give me an example ? What am trying to do is , we have an web application which requires trunk source , sql file , installation path and some more additional files in our SVN repositories. Now the shell script checksout all the necessary files without authorization and create an instance of our application in /var/www folder. Now what i have to do is using jenkins i have to invoke this build.xml file (which consists of shell script) every day at 7:PM so that after it has been done we can run automation scripts on that instance.

Comment: How do you execute a shell script as part of the build? You select "Add build step, and select "shell script".

Comment: @vtiger See the addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David's comments above, its easier to run shell scripts from Jenkins job directly, instead of creating exec task in ant.

Anyways, the error that you are referring to is not caused by Jenkins, Its from SVN server. Your local machine has svn authentication saved, so you don't have to give credentials while accessing SVN through script/directly. Whereas the machine on which you are running build.xml (through Jenkins) doesn't have SVN authentication saved, you have to mention the credentials.

Make sure to add SVN user authentication to your test.sh script. 
Ex:  svn co svn://myrepo/dev/trunk --username jenkins --password PASSWORD

Note: You don't have to add user authentication everytime, you do it once and the machine saves it.

Comment: So if i run my test.sh through jenkins having mentioned the svn authentication details within test.sh will it work successfully as i run in my machine ? Can you give me an example of how to execute a shell script through jenkins ?

Comment: In your Jenkins job, Click on "Add Build Step" button and select "Execute Shell". This will create a new section where you can specify the path of "test.sh" or enter commands directly. Jenkins converts this enter section to a script and runs as "sh" while executing the job.

Comment: check this link for example: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands